# ¿Cómo seteo un header en una petición restful en java?

Tags: java, webservice, rest

Tengo un servicio Rest el cuál consumo así:

```
URL url = new URL(URI);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
```

Ese es uno de los que pruebo y funciona perfectamente, pero ahora necesito consumir otro Rest pero a diferencia del anterior este nuevo necesita que se le configure un valor de autenticación en el header.

¿Cómo configuro una variable llamada **'autenticacion'** con un valor **'x'** en el header de la petición?

Comment: Y probaste con `conn.setRequestProperty("autenticacion", "x");` ?

Comment: Sí, parece que funcionó así. Como según setRequestProperty en su documentación tiene propiedades definidas, no sabía que se le podían agregar propias. Ponlo en respuesta, por fa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con **[`URLConnection#setRequestProperty(String key, String value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)** se configuran los [encabezados HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Cabeceras) (*headers*) de la solicitud, ya sea para los encabezados por defecto (que ya estabas usando), como para encabezados personalizados, como es en tu caso.

Sólo se necesita agregar una línea más luego de instanciar la [conexión](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html#openConnection-java.net.URL-).

```
final String autenticacion = "x";
             //Modificar por lo que quieras

URL url = new URL(URI);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


//Enviamos un header personalizado con su valor
conn.setRequestProperty("autenticacion", autenticacion);


String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
```